# Opening links in new Safari window from web app

Tags: web-applications, safari, ios7

I have a webapp running with meta tag web-app-capable=yes,
when the user loads the application from the home shortcut it runs fullscreen without navigation bars, and this is why I want external links to open in a new safari window rather than inside my own app.

I have tried

```
rel="external"
```

on the <a>'s and also

```
target="_blank"
```

but still no joy.

Important to say - It only happens in iOS7 and not 6.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - It's a big bug, and they appear to know of it and have finished a fix, but when it get deployed is a mystery.

*Original answer below, pre-release:*

iOS 7 is still under NDA as far as I can tell, so until public release it's best you ask on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Not quite, once you have a developer account it's downloadable. You don't need special authorization to register for developer account.
Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Atroy found a soloution here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21629499/2978727

In short terms:

- your link needs `target=xxx` and href to an external site
- get `pdf.output(datauristring)` from your rendered pdf and add it with a hash to the link above
- the external site takes the hash and redirects with `document.location.href=document.location.hash.substring(1)`

It worked for me in iOS 8. Hope that helps for you too.