# iOS 7 (and newer) can't open PDF in new browser window

Tags: web-applications, ios7, jspdf

I have big trouble with jsPDF since iOS7 exists. We developed a Web App and used jsPDF to create PDFs on-the-fly. We open the PDF in a new Safari window so that the user gets access to Adobe Reader to send the PDF via Mail or do other things. In iOS6 this was no problem, but in iOS7 you can't open `data:application/pdf;base64` links in a new window! Note this only happens if you add the Web App to your homescreen.

If someone has a solution, a workaround or other helpful informations I would be glad to hear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a solution!! 
Create a html file (eg pdf.html) and add

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.location.href = document.location.hash.substr(1);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Create a link

```
<a class="btn btn-default" id="pdfData" ng-show="isMobile && pdfReady" ref="app/views/pdf.html" target="xxx">
Download PDF
</a>
```

After you "rendered" your pdf get the `datauristring` and add it to your link as hash.

```
var pdfData = doc.output('datauristring');
var element = document.getElementById('pdfData');
element.href = "app/views/pdf.html#" + pdfData;
element.target = "xxx";
$scope.pdfReady = true; // show download link
```

And now if the user clicks the download link a new window is opened in safari and the pdf get shown

Comment: is it ref or href while creating a link? <a class="btn btn-default" id="pdfData" ng-show="isMobile && pdfReady" href="app/views/pdf.html" target="xxx">
Download PDF
</a>

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `doc.output('dataurlnewwindow')`?

If that doesn't work, you could make a new route like `/pdf/download?data=base64data...` and response the pdf there with `Content-Type: application/pdf` and based on the given parameter data. Be sure to avoid possible security issues, so that no other one can provide pdfs with your url.

Comment: From the [JsDoc Reference](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html#output), the only possible parameters for the output() method are: `dataurlstring` (alias `datauristring`), and `datauri` (alias `dataurl`).

Comment: @SalvatoreZappalà that's not accurate if you check the code there is `dataurlnewwindow` see line 1517 on https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jspdf.js.html

Comment: `dataurlnewwindow` works for desktop new tab but not for mobile.